# Objective-C – UIDatePicker with custom values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, customization, uipickerview, uidatepicker

So ideally I would like to use the UIDatePicker to display dates. But instead of displaying a specific day (for the leftmost component) like `Feb 2` I would like it to display a custom value like i.e `Peter's birthday`.

Is there a way to achieve this with using the `UIDatePicker`? Or do I have to create a `UIPickerView` and feed it with a datasource of dates and my custom values?

If so how would I go about feeding it with dates (what would my dataSource look like)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDatePicker only allows you do pick dates in som predefined styles like date,time,date+time etc..., so you would **have to** go with a UIPickerView.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0: return self.birthdays.count;
        case 1: return 24;
        case 2: return 60;
        default: return -1;
    }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component)
    {
        case 0: return [[self.birthdays objectAtIndex:row] title];
        case 1: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
        case 2: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];
        default: return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I see. How would I go about supplying component 1 with date values like in the UIDatePicker? `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Jan 1", @"Jan 2", nil]` and so on? Can I get the day prefix as well? Like "Sun Jan 1", "Mon Jan 2" and so on?

Comment: You mean component 0 (first) or 1 (second)? I thought you wanted the first one to hold like a custom title...

Comment: Sorry typo. Yes component 0 (first, leftmost component).

Comment: Yes, you should have an array holding either titles or 'Birthday'-objects with a 'title'-property.